# Setting Azure ACLs for a VM outside of it

Tags: azure, acl

Is it possible to set an ACL for a VM without having to install anything on the VM itself?

Dan

Comment: What research have you already done? What have you tried?

Comment: Basically looking to understand if this can be done via an API. somewhat mimicking an AWS Security Group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell scripts

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl-powershell/

https://www.npmjs.org/package/azure-cli

http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/10/29/set-by-step-setting-up-network-access-control-lists-acls-in-azure.aspx

Comment: Specifically the [Set-AzureAclConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495192.aspx) cmdlet.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance... is Azure PowerShell the equivalent of an AWS API?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it in Power Shell:

`Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'foobar' -Name 'foobar' | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name 'Ftp' -Protocol 'TCP' -LocalPort 21 -PublicPort 21 | Update-AzureVM
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'foobar' -Name 'foobar' | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name 'FTPPassive9870' -Protocol 'TCP' -LocalPort 9870 -PublicPort 9870 | Update-AzureVM
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'foobar' -Name 'foobar' | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name 'FTPPassive9872' -Protocol 'TCP' -LocalPort 9872 -PublicPort 9872 | Update-AzureVM
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'foobar' -Name 'foobar' | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name 'FTPPassive9873' -Protocol 'TCP' -LocalPort 9873 -PublicPort 9873 | Update-AzureVM
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'foobar' -Name 'foobar' | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name 'FTPPassive9874' -Protocol 'TCP' -LocalPort 9874 -PublicPort 9874 | Update-AzureVM
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'foobar' -Name 'foobar' | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name 'FTPPassive9875' -Protocol 'TCP' -LocalPort 9875 -PublicPort 9875 | Update-AzureVM`